# Paypal Rest api: billing plan, payment_definitions meaning of "cycles"

Tags: paypal

I would like to setup a paypal billing plan with monthly payments similar to e.g. [github](https://github.com/account/plans). The customer gets charged $7 every month.

I am struggling with the property cycles. The [api document](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#paymentdefinition-object) says cycles = "Number of cycles in this payment definition".

Does this mean the payment definition has to include the values:

```
"frequency_interval": "1",
"frequency": "MONTH",
"cycles": "1",
```

Or should cycles have the value "0"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what i understood, cycles it's the number of time the payment will be done (if you put 12, it will last 12 occurency -> 1 year). You can put 0 only if the plan's type is "INFINITE", the plan will last forever until you stop it.

So you have to put 0 if you want it never to stop.

Comment: Could you provide me with a link pointing to where you found this information?

Comment: I tried to put 0 when the plan's type was not infinite and the answer was "You can put 0 only if the type is infinite" so i deducted it that 0 means never stop

Comment: You actually need to put `0` in `cycles` and `INFINITE` in the `type` of the create plan main object (there are two `type` fields, so watch out!)
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-a-plan